# Change in size with distance based on perspective

Tags: geometry

EDIT: The original question has been answered with the relationship: `angular diameter=2arctan(L/2D)`. I have a follow up question.

Original question:

> How can I calculate the change in size of an object based on the
> distance from it, due to perspective?
>
> More specifically what is the relationship between size and distance,
> as accurate as possible, in a mathematical description?

Follow up question

> On Wikipedia entry for angular diameter
> (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter#Formula) we are also
> shown the equation: `angular diameter = 2arcsin(L/2D)`. I don't quite
> understand why this would be valid, let alone more appropriate for
> large angular sizes.

Comment: Please don't edit a question to include a follow-up, as it invalidates the answers you were given.  Instead, _please post a new question_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the object has physical size $L$ and is $D$ away from you, you can draw a line from your eye to the center of the object and lines from your eye to the ends of the object.  There are two right triangles with one leg $\frac L2$ and the other $D$.  The angle at your eye of each triangle is $\arctan \left(\frac L{2D}\right)$ so the total angle is $2\arctan \left(\frac L{2D}\right)$.  When $x \ll 1, \arctan x \approx x$ and this becomes $\frac LD$

Comment: That answers my question, thanks! I have a follow up. On wikipedia entry for angular diameter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter#Formula) that equation is also shown. However, it is also showing 2arcsin(d/2D) for large angular sizes, although I don't quite understand the explanation as to why this would be more appropriate. Could you expand on that?

Comment: The explanation is in the paragraph just below the formula.  Draw a picture of your eye and a circle with the tangent lines from your eye to the circle.  The right angle is at the tangent lines, not at the line to the center of the circle.  You should have included what you had found in the question initially and asked your real question.

Comment: I thought it would be better to ask the general question first in case I was misunderstanding that part. I changed the question to reflect the follow up. So what you're saying is that the angle between the tangent line and the radius would be the right angle here?

Comment: That is correct.